# Internet connection problems in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, connection

I took a vps server to ubuntu to use it as a rdp. I connected to it via ssh, installed ubuntu-desktop and xRDP. I managed to connect to it, but the Internet does not work on it - there are no available connections. Sometimes, after rebooting, I can do something from the terminal, for example, sudo apt, but most often it just gives errors like this when entering via ssh: `Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release- lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings.`
When I try to check the ping to 8.8.8.8, the packets go through. Last time I tried, I was able to download the speedtest-cli package, it shows good speed. But there is no Internet inside the interface. I am new to linux and this is a very unexpected behavior for me. I really count on your help. [print screen #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgKci.png) [print screen #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLfp9.png)[print screen #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQbVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

`sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`

fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was solved by updating ca certificates using

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```